# Blender Performence Issues

Tags: performance

My blender has been lagging very badly lately. I don't know what to do. please help.

my laptop performance details

Intel Core i5-4200U
CPU 2.30 GHz
RAM 8.00 GB

Comment: Is it independent of the complexity of your scene? Do you use more RAM than usual? Can you give us additional information about what might have changed that causes the issues?

Comment: I think we can't do anything for it, I too have a laptop and I know the pain, well the hardware problem can only be fixed by buying a new desktop with same configuration but with a video card!

Comment: Don't increase the subsurf in view to more than 2